# Binding no Spring MVC não funcionando

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Bem, tenho um problema no qual nunca me ocorreu antes relacionado ao binding do Spring MVC.

Tenho um formulário como abaixo. O bindind **"firstName"** e **"lastName"** funcionam certinho, mas já o **"logins.email"** dá problema.

```
<f:form class="form-signin" method="post" action="addAgency" modelAttribute="tenant">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon entypo-user"></span>
        <f:input path="firstName" type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Nome" />
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon entypo-user"></span>
        <f:input path="lastName" type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Sobrenome" />
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon entypo-mail"></span>
        <f:input path="logins.email" type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="E-mail" />logins
    </div>

        <!-- Restante de Formulário -->
```

O Seguinte stackTrace é exibido:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'logins.email' of bean class [br.com.joocebox.model.Agency]: Bean property 'logins.email' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:716)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.landing.register_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005finput_005f2(register_jsp.java:275)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.landing.register_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fform_005f0(register_jsp.java:138)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.landing.register_jsp._jspService(register_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:688)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:682)
    org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.landing_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(landing_jsp.java:268)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.landing_jsp._jspService(landing_jsp.java:131)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Bem, o problema é que eu tenho os respectivos getters e setters em meu projeto. Abaixo estão os modelos de forma reduzida:

Agencia.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="agency")
@NamedQuery(name="Agency.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Agency a")
public class Agency implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_agency")
    private Long idAgency;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="subdomain")
    private String subdomain;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Login
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="agency")
    private Set<Login> logins;

    public Agency() {
    }

    public Long getIdLogin(){
        return idAgency;
    }

    public void setIdLogin(Long idLogin) {
        this.idAgency = idLogin;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSubdomain() {
        return this.subdomain;
    }

    public void setSubdomain(String subdomain) {
        this.subdomain = subdomain;
    }

    public Set<Login> getLogins() {
        return logins;
    }

    public void setLogins(Set<Login> logins) {
        this.logins = logins;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID=" + idAgency + ", Sub-Dominio=" + subdomain;
    }

}
```

**Login.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="login")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name="tenant_id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty=PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@NamedQuery(name="Login.findAll", query="SELECT l FROM Login l")
public class Login implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_login")
    private Long idLogin;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="master")
    private Boolean master;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Agency
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_agency")
    private Agency agency;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="user_role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    public Login() {
    }

    public Long getIdLogin() {
        return this.idLogin;
    }

    public void setIdLogin(Long idLogin) {
        this.idLogin = idLogin;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Boolean getMaster() {
        return this.master;
    }

    public void setMaster(Boolean master) {
        this.master = master;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Agency getAgency() {
        return this.agency;
    }

    public void setAgency(Agency agency) {
        this.agency = agency;
    }

    public Long getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Spring MVC não vai fazer o *binding* de um campo para um conjunto.

Entretanto, se a ideia é receber uma lista de e-mails separadas por vírgula, só para citar um exemplo, uma solução simples seria criar um *setter* que recebe uma `String` e usa o `split` para quebrar em vários itens, adicionando-os no conjunto.

Além disso, o *getter* correspondente juntaria os elementos do conjunto, separando-os por vírgulas, e retornaria o resultado em uma única `String`.

Comment: Então utluiz, estou começando a achar que minha regra de negocio está errada, pois o que eu gostaria é de uma pagina de cadastro onde novos clientes iriam informar um primeiro login e senha do sistema, pois futuramente novos usuários poderiam ser cadastrados. Será que devo fazer @OneToOne? Obrigado

Comment: @JoãoManolo Realmente parece que há inconsistências, mas sem conhecer o domínio do seu sistema fica muito difícil dizer a forma "correta", já que diferentes situações exigem diferentes soluções. Se precisar de ajuda, sugiro postar uma nova questão conceitual colocando seu modelo atual. Há algumas perguntas assim por aqui às vezes e geralmente elas obtém boas respostas.

Comment: Oi @utluiz. Acabei demorando para entender aqui o que eu estava fazendo, mas acabei chegando a conclusão de que eu estava totalmente errado em minha abordagem. Depois de pensar muito e analisar alguns projetos achados na web pude fazer algumas alterações fazendo assim o que gostaria de ter feito a principio. Claro que agora surgiram novos problemas, mas isso é assunto para um outro post. Obrigado e Abraços!

Comment: @JoãoManolo Legal! Muito bom ver que você conseguiu aprender e evoluir. Sucesso!